# Help to find the equation of the tangent line to the graph of the the curve at the point (1,4)

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{x+\sqrt{y}}{y+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{3y-9x}{x+y}$$

How do I approach this kind question? I couldn't figure it out....

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. You are encouraged to show any work or progress you have had with the question. It may help encourage others to help you.

Comment: Are you familiar with implicit differentiation?

Comment: not too much, I am so confused

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the equation as the level-set to a function of two variables:

$$f(x,y) = \frac{x+\sqrt{y}}{y+\sqrt{x}} - \frac{3y-9x}{x+y} = 0$$

Now what do we know of two variable functions? They have approximations  by Taylor polynomials (much like one variable functions). The Taylor expansion of first order of a function is a plane, and the level sets of a plane are... lines!